# Predict function producing fewer rows than provided

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I am currently trying to run the following code:

```
pv_model <- glm(SalePrice ~ MSSubClass + MSZoning..., data = train)
summary(pv_model)
pv_predict <- predict(pv_model)
train$PV <- pv_predict
```

However, when I try to assign the predictions as a column in the train data set, I get this error:

```
Error: Assigned data `predict(pv_model)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 730 rows.
x Assigned data has 540 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

Upon further inspection, it looks like my pv_predict variable only contains 540 rows, despite pv_model having 730. What accounts for this difference? Why does the predict function eliminate so many rows, and what can I do to fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Missing data in the training set might be the issue.  Try:

```
predict(pv_model, newdata=train)
```

This will use all the rows, and give you `NA` where there is missing data in a predictor.

Comment: or use `na.action = na.exclude` in the original `glm` fit.